# Unable to open X509 store

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate

I am using the below method to get certificate from the x509 store

```
private X509Certificate GetCert(string certThumbPrint)
    {

        var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbPrint.Trim(), false);
        certStore.Close();
        // Check to see if our certificate was added to the collection. If no, throw an error, if yes, create a certificate using it.
        if (0 == certCollection.Count || certCollection.Count == null)
        {
            throw new ApiException(string.Format("Error: Admin Service Client  : No certificate found containing thumbprint {0}",certThumbPrint), ApiLogCategory.Configuration, ErrorCodes.AdminServiceClient);
        }
        var cert = new X509Certificate(certCollection[0].RawData, string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        return cert;

    }
```

I was getting error so I tried debugging and found that the application is unable to open the X509 store. What can I do in this case.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I got error when the application was trying to access the api using the certificate which was not there. While debugging I found that the application was unable to open X509 store and the exception is "system.security.cryptography.cryptographicexception"

Comment: The exception should also have a message associated with it, can you show that?

Comment: Message = "The X509 certificate store has not been opened."

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

Comment: Most resources in Windows have access control. So if the process identity of your application (on IIS or IIS Express) must have access to the certificate store, so as to get rid of the exception.

Comment: @LexLi Could you please elaborate on how this issue can be resolved

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permission related issue.

Is your certificate installed in personal store?

if so, Right click the certificate => All tasks => Manage private key => Add IIS AppPool\AppPoolName and grant it Full control

if you're running app pool under a different account than application pool identity then that that user.

Comment: I have added Everyone instead of AppPool\AppPoolName and given full control. Will that suffice?

Comment: Grant access to that user rather than Everyone. you'll need to type the name into the select identity dialogues

Comment: I am still getting the same error. This is not a certificate issue, instead the application is unable to get access to the x509 store